# Can Aluminum Hydroxide (Al(OH)3) be heated to it's melting temperature before decomposing?

Tags: melting-point, decomposition

On the [wikipedia page for aluminum hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_hydroxide) the listed melting point is 300 °C (572 °F), but in the same page it states that aluminum hydroxide decomposes at only 180 °C (356 °F). Can aluminum hydroxide be melted without decomposing?

Comment: The decomposition of pure aluminium hydroxide to water and oxide takes place above 550 °C. What you were reading in Wikipedia refers to the use in a mixture as a fire retardant.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Do you have a source for the decomposition temperature of pure aluminum hydroxide? I am trying to find good resources for chemical properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL.DR:** Aluminium oxide (sometimes known as alumina) is made by heating the aluminium hydroxide to a temperature of about 1100 - 1200°C. ([Chemguide](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/extraction/aluminium.html))

$$\ce{Al(OH)3 ->[\Delta] Al2O3 + 3H2O}$$

---

As @andselisk said, the temperature [Wikipedia mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_hydroxide) is aluminium hydroxide mixture in a fire retardant which might have other compounds. Decomposition of pure aluminium hydroxide has been studied in various papers and its decomposition reaction mechanism, temperature, reaction kinetics has been exhaustively studied.

A paper examines$\ce{^{[1]}}$ the decomposition of aluminium hydroxide at a temperature of 973-1123 K(700 °C-850 °C).

Another paper$\ce{^{[2]}}$ shows aluminium hydroxide being heated from room temperature to 1200 K(926.85 °C) where the exact temperature of decomposition products i.e $\ce{Al2O3}$ is noted:

> [...] we find the first and the smallest endothermic peak at **519
>   K**, which is due to the partial dehydroxylation of gibbsite
>   ($\ce{Al(OH)3}$) and formation of boehmite ($\ce{AlOOH}$). Endothermic
>   peak at **585 K** corresponds to two processes: (i) transformation of
>   gibbsite to phase $\ce{χ-Al2O3}$ and (ii) additional conversion of
>   gibbsite to boehmite. The first process is in accordance with the
>   results obtained. Another endothermic peak at **815 K** is due to
>   decomposition of boehmite and formation of alumina $\ce{γ-Al2O3}$. The
>   obtained TG curves show clearly three steps of weight loss. The weight
>   loss in the first step (about 5 wt.%) is due to the partial
>   transformation of gibbsite to boehmite; the second step (about 25
>   wt.%) corresponds to decomposition of gibbsite to boehmite, otherwise
>   to $\ce{χ-Al2O3}$. The last step of around 3 wt.% relates to the
>   formation of $\ce{γ-Al2O3}$. Further observations show that the total weight
>   loss is equal to 33 wt.%. All these transformations of gibbsite and
>   the chemical composition are confirmed by the XRD analysis.

**References**

1. Chemical kinetics and reaction mechanism of thermal decomposition of aluminum hydroxide and magnesium hydroxide at high temperature (973-1123 K) by Ienwhei Chen, Shuh Kwei Hwang, and Shyan Chen, Ind. Eng. Chem. Res. **1989**, 28, 6, 738–742 DOI: [https://doi.org/10.1021/ie00090a015](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ie00090a015)
2. http://przyrbwn.icm.edu.pl/APP/PDF/131/a131z3p62.pdf
3. Bhattacharya, Indra & Das, S. & Mukherjee, P. & Paul, Subir & Mitra, P.. (**2004**). Thermal Decomposition of Precipitated Fine Aluminium Trihydroxide. Scandinavian Journal of Metallurgy. 33. 211 - 219. 10.1111/j.1600-0692.2004.00686.x.([DOI](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229868061_Thermal_Decomposition_of_Precipitated_Fine_Aluminium_Trihydroxide)) (Here aluminium hydroxide is subjected to dehydration upto a temperature of 1440 °C)